# Winforms: Why do events fire at design-time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, windows-forms-designer

Why are messages displayed at design-time?

My code is :

```
class Class1 : TextBox
{
    public Class1()
    {
        this.Resize += new EventHandler(Class1_Resize);
    }

    void Class1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Resize");
    }
}
```

Pic :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Because that's the way the Form designer works.  It's actually instantiating your control when it displays it in your form at design-time.  Thus when you resize the control in the designer, your code for the message box fires.

Comment: +1. Checking with  `if (!DesignMode)` should help resolve the OP's issue.

Comment: Checking `(!DesignMode)` in constructor won't help (since object is not created yet, designer cannot set DesignMode = true).

Comment: @max: Good point; either conditionally registering the handler on `OnLoad`, or conditionally suppressing the action in the handler itself is the way to go.

Comment: This works in constructor: bool designMode = LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime;