# How do I prevent Visual Studio from firing events on the designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-designer

I've got a user control which is supposed to fire an event when the visibility or the enable status changes.

My problem is the events fire on Visual Studio's designer too, which is irritating since during design they act in an unexpected behaviour.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: I guess it's winforms, right?

Comment: @DanielBahmani yes

Comment: did u chk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901220/winforms-why-do-events-fire-at-design-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Winforms: Why do events fire at design-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901220/winforms-why-do-events-fire-at-design-time)

Comment: Does [DesignMode with Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34664) help?  E.g. I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35041620).

Answer (score 1):

Add this property to your (base) class and check its value in the `RaiseEventXYZ` or `FireEventXYZ` methods...

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool IsDesignMode { get;private set; }
    public MyClass()
    {
        IsDesignMode = LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in VS 2022, and most likely not in VS2019 and 2017